# SQLite add milliseconds to time

Tags: sqlite, date

I have a sqlite database where I want to add 84 seconds to each time filed. The time is formatted like this:

> yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:zzz
>
> 2017-12-15 11:50:12.132

I've tried to modify the time with

```
UPDATE sensordata
SET time=DATETIME(time, '+84.000 seconds')
```

This adds 84 seconds correctly, but it deletes the milliseconds:

> 2017-12-15 11:51:36

How can I add the seconds and still have the milliseconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `datetime` function does not format the fractional part.

You can use `strftime()` with the exact format you want :

(Edited to remove the redundant `%S`)

```
UPDATE sensordata
SET time=STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', time, '+84.000 seconds')
```

In fact `datetime(...)` is equivalent to `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', ...)`, see [Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more details.

Comment: The result: 2017-12-15 11:51:36.36.059

Comment: So there is a millisecond part, but it has wrong value ? I don't understand why, if I try `select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '2017-12-15 11:50:12.132', '+84.000 seconds') ` I get `2017-12-15 11:51:36.36.132`

Comment: @CL. Correct, I didn't even see that `36` appeared 2 times in my comment !

Comment: Now it works the right way. Thank you! I should have written that the seconds where doubled. Sorry